# WSO2 EI Multiple certificates per endpoint

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

For this situation I'm using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0

I currently find myself in the situation where I have 1 endpoint (SOAP) controlled by government (which I need to use) and multiple of our end customers need to connect to. In order for this to work, all the end customers need to address the same endpoint in the same fashion but using their **own** client certificate.

So customer 1 has certificate 1 and customer 2 needs certificate 2, etc.

AS far I as could tell, from documentation and trying, one endpoint can only ever use a single certificate in its connection. Since the amount of customers might change on a daily basis I would to have a single common solution to this problem.

Currently to circumvent this problem I'm creating a design in which I use endpoint per customer and a reverse proxy to connect to the final endpoint. This is however not ideal since I would still need to create 1 endpoint per customer, which might turn out to be pretty intensive.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you cannot get the ESB to present a different certificate based on the client that is trying to connect. If you really want to go down that route putting a reverse proxy (like nginx) in front of the ESB and using that to handle the SSL could work, but I wouldn't really recommend doing that.

If you are wanting mutual SSL ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20217063/3386758), [link](http://soasecurity.org/2012/08/08/enable-mutual-ssl-for-proxy-services-in-wso2esb-i/)) then you need to add the certificates of the clients that will be connecting to your endpoint to your client trust store. The default truststore is located at `<wso2EI_home>/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks`. To import a cert `keytool -import -trustcacerts -file <cert-file-name> -alias <choose-a-useful-name> -keystore client-truststore.jks` The default password is `wso2carbon`.

Doing this does require you to maintain the certificates, when a client cert changes because it expired you need to import the new one. They won't be able to connect until you do.

Another option could be to disable mutual SSL and have you endpoint open for anyone (that you allow through your firewall) to be able to connect. You won't have to maintain a list of client certificates. The traffic will still be encrypted, you will just lose the tight control over who can connect.

Comment: In the current situation I'm already checking who comes in. Problem is that everyone uses the same information inside the message, so the chance of fraudulent messages increases. In the ESB we need to match client certificate with some of the message contents in order to verify that the sender is indeed who he says he is. Given that they are not required to send from the same location (i.e. ip-address) this is unfortunately not a problem I can solve this way. I will mark this answer as the answer though, because I now know that my situation is indeed not possible. Thanks!